# Passing a large JSON object from JSP to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, json, jsp, servlets

I know the question of passing Json from servlet/Jsp to javascript has been asked a lot, but my Json object is huge and contains around 400 records.
I have tried passing it from jsp to javascript as follows:

`var json = ${json};`

but the json object breakes and doesn't finish till the last record. When i print the json object in the servlet it has no breaks. I basically have a servlet which generates a JSON result and passes it to a JSP file and i want the result to be used to plot poly-lines and points on google map. There is no request being  sent form the jsp to my servlet. 
I am really a novice coder.

I use RequestDispatcher to send the data to jsp as follows:

```
request.setAttribute("json", json1);
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("result.jsp");
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

While execution the HTML page is not completely generated:
[HTML-break](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ED5f.png)

The jsp code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-  8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js">
</script>
<%
JSONObject json = (JSONObject)request.getAttribute("json");
%>
<script>
var json = ${json};
function initialize() {
//Set of statements
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="googleMap" style="width:1000px;height:1000px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is in the statement `var json = ${json};`

Comment: Have you closed script after json declaration?

Comment: Yeah I have closed the script tag. In the picture the json records are not completely embedded in javascript. They terminate after a certain number of records.

Comment: This generally happens when an exception is thrown by one of your objects during the JSON marshaling.

Comment: I have checked it works for smaller json objects. Is there a length limitation for passing data from the server to client(jsp to javascript) using this method?

Comment: No there is no such limitation.
Can you please validate your json? http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Yeah it's a valid Json file.  [Validity](http://postimg.org/image/6khk7ps8f/)